# Why doesn't silica gel dissolve in ethyl acetate

Tags: polarity

Why doesn't silica gel dissolve in ethyl acetate when something like aspirin does. Both silica gel and ethyl acetate are highly polar. I though like dissolved like.

Comment: Neither aspirin, nor ethyl acetate are **highly** polar, but rather moderately.

Comment: @Mithoron, add the fact that silica is a network solid, so it does not dissolve in much of anything (except for what reacts with it), and you have good answer.

Comment: If "like dissolves like" were the only rule, then your bathtub would get dissolved in water, together with much of your kitchenware. Oh, and your car would be gone completely, because it has both polar and non-polar liquids in it.

Comment: but seriously. if that rule is incorrect, why is it taught. i guess its akin to the i before e rule.

Comment: Come on. Every empirical rule has its limitations.

Comment: It is not *incorrect*, it is just limited.

Comment: Not even methanol or water do a good job of dissolving silica gel (although water is better at it than most other solvents). I haven’t actually tried DMF, which is supposed to be one of the most polar solvents out there, though.

Comment: @BenNorris Silicon dioxide does dissolve in hi-pressure hi-temperature water. http://www.minsocam.org/ammin/AM62/AM62_1052.pdf

Answer (score 5):

Because (among other things) silica is not actually polar. Yes, theoretically a molecule of $\ce{SiO2}$ should have some degree of polarity to it. However, silica as a solid does not exist as single molecules.

Silica exists as a network of $\ce{Si}$ cations bonded together by $\ce{O}$ anions. One way of looking at it would be to say that each small bead of silica gel (or any other form of silica, glass or quartz) is one huge single molecule of silica.